# Which version of QuantLib is the basis for QLNet ?

Tags: quantlib

I am trying to find the version of QuantLib on which QLNet (its C# version) is based, but I can't find it. Do you have any idea what it is?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically the answer is none. QLNet is a remake of the C++ library, but it's not a direct port. It's not complete but the most important classes are there (such as TermStructure). It's a product that the developers translate their understanding of the C++ library into and thus not directly associated with any particular version of the C++ library.